# How to implement a one time authentication mechanism?

Tags: authentication, web

I'm trying to create a website to authenticate users through the use of a throwaway password where the assumption is that the user might not use the website again (basically a one time access).

I have done my research on OTP and various solutions to authentication but these don't seem to fit my requirements, most of them seem to rely on users having login credentials to the website whereas my system would allow them access without the need for registering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implementation of [passwordless authentication](https://auth0.com/docs/connections/passwordless) by Auth0 seems to fit what you're describing. Even if you were not considering a third-party provider it may be useful to go through the documentation.

Basically, a user can login to a site without any need for a sign-up process. They can do so just by requesting that a one time code is delivered to them, for example, either by email or SMS.

This way, they can get quick access without having to setup a user and in the event that they do come back your application can recognize this because they will most likely be using the same mechanism, that is, you can use the email or mobile phone as the unique identifier.

**Disclosure:** I'm an Auth0 engineer.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not require your users to register, why do you need authentication at all?

Why not just set a cookie with an unique identifier on the first visit? You can store data at the server side associated with that identifier. Keep track of when you last saw the user, and if they do not return within a certain period, you can delete any data you stored for that user.